# using reduce function on list of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, salesforce, reduce

I have number of objects im receiving weekly, each one on these object has date, hours, and other fields. I wanna sort these object array  total hours of each day.

example of the objects

```
var anArray = [{
  'End':"22:00",
  'Id':"Q45575",
  'Name':"W-299849",
  'Start':"20:00",
  'date':"2018-02-04",
  'hours':2
},{
  'End':"21:00",
  'Id':"Q45551",
  'Name':"W-299809",
  'Start':"15:00",
  'date':"2018-02-07",
  'hours':5
},{
  'End':"20:00",
  'Id':"Q45515",
  'Name':"W-299849",
  'Start':"10:00",
  'date':"2018-02-04",
  'hours':2
}];
```

output should be like this, assuming sunday is 2/4

Sun Mon tue Wed fri sat

4 0 0 5 0 0

This what I have

```
  var resourceData = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  var targetDay = new Date(c.date).getDay() === 6 ? 0 : (new Date(c.date).getDay() + 1);
  if (a) {
    a['week'][targetDay] += c.hours;
  } else {
    a = { 'week': new Array(7).fill(0) };
    a['week'][targetDay] = c.hours;
  }
  return a;
}, {});
```

is not working im getting error with targetDay

Comment: You have a typo in your code.   `c.hourse` should be `c.hours`

Comment: @TaylorAckley was typo error im still facing the same problem

Comment: `please only in javascript no jquery.`  so why have you used a `jquery` tag?.  You wouldn't use jquery to do this anyway.

Comment: @Keith jquery works sorry i will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes almost reached the finish line.

You can let initialValue for the reduce is `{ 'week': new Array(7).fill(0) }`, don't need to compare with `if(a)` in the handler of reduce.

See the comments in below codes:

```js
var anArray = [{  'End':"22:00",  'Id':"Q45575",  'Name':"W-299849",  'Start':"20:00",  'date':"2018-02-04",  'hours':2},{  'End':"21:00",  'Id':"Q45551",  'Name':"W-299809",  'Start':"15:00",  'date':"2018-02-07",  'hours':5},{  'End':"20:00",  'Id':"Q45515",  'Name':"W-299849",  'Start':"10:00",  'date':"2018-02-04",  'hours':2}];

var resourceData = anArray.reduce((a, c) => {
  var targetDay = new Date(c.date).getDay() === 6 ? 0 : (new Date(c.date).getDay() + 1);
  a['week'][targetDay] += c.hours;

  /*
  else {
    a = { 'week': new Array(7).fill(0) };
    a['week'][targetDay] = c.hours;
  }*/ //remove else block because already created [var a] by the initialValue
  return a;
}, { 'week': new Array(7).fill(0) }); //initialize with expected object instead of {}

console.log(resourceData)
```

Comment: The `if (a)` test is also not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reduce, for this I think forEach seems a better fit.

Example below.

```js
var anArray = [{
  'End':"22:00",
  'Id':"Q45575",
  'Name':"W-299849",
  'Start':"20:00",
  'date':"2018-02-04",
  'hours':2
},{
  'End':"21:00",
  'Id':"Q45551",
  'Name':"W-299809",
  'Start':"15:00",
  'date':"2018-02-07",
  'hours':5
},{
  'End':"20:00",
  'Id':"Q45515",
  'Name':"W-299849",
  'Start':"10:00",
  'date':"2018-02-04",
  'hours':2
}];

var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

var result = {};

//lets just zero every day
(new Array(7).fill(0)).map((x,ix) => { 
  result[days[ix]] = 0;
});

//now lets add them up
anArray.forEach((d) => {
  var dt = new Date(d.date);
  result[days[dt.getDay()]] += d.hours;
});

console.log(result);
```